# Wallet Host Error

Tags: wallet-recovery

I have a little bit of a bitcoin in Rushwallet.  Rushwallet is closing on April 15, 2018, but last night there is a Host Error and it's still not connecting today with the same Host Error.  If I have my Private Key, can I move them to any wallet?  Also, I'm not positive the number I have is the private key, it's about 41 characters long. Thank you

Comment: Does your private key start with `xprv`, `zprv`?

Comment: If you got the private key from rushwallet, it must be wallet import format, which starts with the number 5 and 51 characters. Are you sure yours is 41 characters?

Comment: No, I am not sure. I guess this means I lost my bitcoin.  Rushwallet had a notice that it would be closing on April 15, 2018 but when I login there is always a Host Error. Do you know of a way to get it back?

Comment: I am sure it is 41 characters but is doesn't start with 5 and 51.  I don't think it is the Private Key now

Comment: Adam, It doesn't start with those letters you have.

Comment: I know how to help you recover rushwallet
bitcoins. I can also help restore lost rushwallets (also if you lost your password, but still know the URL (at least partially)). Sorry, however this is not a free service, because it requires some time and spent computer capacity, with suggestions you can write to the email address specified in my profile. Please describe the request in detail.